# App icon not appearing in Activity app using HealthKit

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I'm using HealthKit to record and store workouts in the Health app. Everything appears just fine in the Health app. When I check the Apple Activity app I'm able to see my workout but I'm unable to see my app's icon.

I've manually added workouts via the Health app and I've also added workouts with Strava. The Activity app shows both these apps' icons properly. For some reason mine is still missing.

This is the best description I've seen of this issue: https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/healthkit-save-workout-set-icon-for-activity-app/42846/3

Has anyone else experienced this?

I'm using Xcode 10.1 and this happens on all devices.

Thanks in advance!

Here's how I'm creating the workout:

```
let workout = HKWorkout(activityType: .mixedCardio,
                                start: startDate,
                                end: endDate,
                                duration: duration,
                                totalEnergyBurned: energyBurned,
                                totalDistance: totalDistance,
                                device: wearableDevice, metadata: nil)
```

Comment: In assets.xcassets, are all the app icon sizes there? Is there anywhere else, like Spotlight search, where your app icon does not appear? Instead of your app icon, do you see that standard white one with black lines on it?

Comment: @pob21 check you are having correct sizes of your app icon in assets.xcassets. I don't think it has any connection in your code.

Comment: Take a screenshot of the missing icon and add it to your question

Comment: @Daniel no the app icons are fine. The workout shows as normal in the actual health app. For some reason it’s just missing in Activity.

Comment: @staticVoidMan unfortunately I’m not able to. There’s some proprietary naming that wouldn’t allow for that. But if you look at any other workouts listed in Activity it appears just like those, there’s just no icon shown. It’s a blank space.

Comment: I have the same issue. Starting a workout from the watch gives me the correct round icon, but from the phone it’s just blank. I’m not using the workout builder on the phone like I am on the watch, I’m just manually adding a workout when the user clicks done so maybe that’s it. Did you find out how to fix it or did it just resolve itself?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried these ?

1. Make sure the app icon is included in the WatchKit app bundle (and check the same even in the extension).

[image: Target setting for app icon]

2. App icons meets all of the criteria Apple has set. Like the dimensions of the icons.

[image: app icon set for watch os]

3. Check in the Watch App Target if this AppIcon set is set as the Apps Icons Source.

[image: general]